# Java 8 - DateTimeFormatter and ISO_INSTANT issues with ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

So I would expect this code to work under the new Java 8 date/time package since all it does is to convert a given ZonedDateTime to string and back using the same built-in DateTimeFormatter instance (ISO_INSTANT):

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(
    now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT),
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
```

But apparently  it doesn't:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-09-01T19:37:48.549Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=549, NanoOfSecond=549000000, MicroOfSecond=549000, InstantSeconds=1409600268},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
```

I have seen this entry already, but it didn't help me because a need a ZonedDateTime object and not a local one and also because I already have 8u20 installed: [Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor using DateTimeFormatter and ZonedDateTime in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596530/unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-temporalaccessor-using-datetimeformatter-and)

Anyone have any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `ISO_INSTANT` formatter is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) - "This is a special case formatter intended to allow a human readable form of an Instant". As such, this formatter is intended for use with an `Instant` not a `ZonedDateTime`.

### Formatting

When formatting, `ISO_INSTANT` can format any temporal object that can provide `ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS` and `ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND`. Both `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` can provide these two fields, thus both work:

```
// works with Instant
Instant instant = Instant.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(instant));

// works with ZonedDateTime 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));

// example output
2014-09-02T08:05:23.653Z
```

### Parsing

When parsing, `ISO_INSTANT` will only produce `ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS` and `ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND`. An `Instant` can be built from those two fields, but `ZonedDateTime` requires a `ZoneId` as well:

To parse a `ZonedDateTime` it is essential that a time-zone `ZoneId` is present. The time-zone can be (a) parsed from the string, or (b) specified to the formatter (using JDK 8u20):

```
// option a - parsed from the string
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2014-09-02T08:05:23.653Z", f);

// option b - specified in the formatter - REQUIRES JDK 8u20 !!!
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2014-09-02T08:05:23.653Z", f);
```

See documentation for [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME), [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) and [`ISO_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME) (any of these three can be used to parse a `ZonedDateTime` without specifying `withZone()`).

### Summary

The `ISO_INSTANT` formatter is a special case formatter designed to work with `Instant`. If you are using a `ZonedDateTime` you should use a different formatter, such as `ISO_DATE_TIME` or `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that the final Z on the generated string is a time zone designator for UTC, so the string does contain a time zone designator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators). However, the documentation does state that this will only work for instants so you are absolutely right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but this might be a bug in Java 8. Maybe it was intended to behave in this way, but I think that the workaround I'm going to propose to you should be the default behavior (when no ZoneId is specified, just take system default):

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out
    .println(ZonedDateTime.parse(now.format(formatter), formatter));
```

There's a similar bug which was fixed in OpenJDK: [JDK-8033662](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033662) - but it's only similar, not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the expected behaviour or not (it probably is) but technically the `ISO_INSTANT` formatter does not include a time zone. If you try with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` formatter instead you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `org.threeten.bp` from **Java 1.8**, here's a **Cheat Sheet** on dealing with String to Date and vice versa.

**Date to String**

```
val date = Date()
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = date }
val zonedDateTime = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(calendar)
val formattedDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(zonedDateTime)
```

**String to Date**

```
val dateString = "2020-03-04T09:04:43.835Z"
val dateInstant = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(dateString))
DateTimeUtils.toDate(dateInstant)
```