# Parse UTC date using java.time

Tags: groovy

I am having an issue trying to parse a date using java.time.LocalDateTime.parse.  I am sure that it is something silly that I am completely overlooking, but cannot for the life of me figure it out.  If the date string does not have a "Z" at the end it works fine, but if it does it will fail during the parse.

Was referencing: [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

[ISO_INSTANT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

Code:

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter



class GroovyPrintExample {
    static void main(String[] args) {


        def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
        def test = "2015-11-12T14:11:03.354Z"
        def dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(test, formatter)


    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612129/java-8-datetimeformatter-and-iso-instant-issues-with-zoneddatetime this may help you

Comment: Thanks Jerry06 I just saw that.  I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z is for timezone, right?
Have you tried using [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead?

Comment: Hi Ervi, I will try that. I thought for sure I had, but will do so again. Saw this linked that seems strange http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612129/java-8-datetimeformatter-and-iso-instant-issues-with-zoneddatetime?lq=1

Comment: That was it.  Doh....thought for sure I had tried that.  Must have used it elsewhere.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad to help, @scarpacci!