# Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing a date string generated from a ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I format a ZonedDateTime then attempt to parse it and get the following exception.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     String timeStr=ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
     System.out.println(timeStr);
     ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStr,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
}
```

resulting exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-10-05T21:38:26.191Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=191000, MilliOfSecond=191, InstantSeconds=1475703506, NanoOfSecond=191000000},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
```

I need to be able to convert time to and from that string format. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 - DateTimeFormatter and ISO\_INSTANT issues with ZonedDateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612129/java-8-datetimeformatter-and-iso-instant-issues-with-zoneddatetime)

Comment: thanks, it is , that answer solved my issue.